# Android Studio - Login/Register stuck at Checking Network

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, network-protocols

I recently started learning android studio and working on a app. The first part of my app is to require login or registration to continue, then it is suppose to be directed to the main/home screen. To create this process I followed this [tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html/4)

Everything seems to be fine up until I try registering or reset password. I first tested in wamp on local host and then moved it to a live server, I've changed the URLs and edited the config file. I've added internet and wifi permissions in the manifest file as well.

I can show my code but Im not sure which code has to be seen to help me out, theres database files, android studio files etc. If you take a look at the tutorial you will probably know more or less where Im probably going wrong.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<?php
/**
* Database config variables
*/
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "IPUTMYPASSWORD");
define("DB_DATABASE", "myapp_login_api");
?>
```

Comment: can you show us your urls config in addition of your log cat screen ?

Comment: For URLS config, are you referring to the config.php file? @samiboussacsou

Comment: Android and config.php

Answer (score 0):

i remember that when I connect my device to my local wlan network it is able to request localhost via 10.0.2.2.
So in your configuration or in your Activity when you try to connect to your localhost, you should use 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1.

to verify the web part try to simulate requests via the browser!

good luck